# How to register a decorator or add a middleware to a third party view function?

Tags: django, view, decorator, django-middleware

I use django-allauth for account management including signup. The built-in url in allauth app for signup is `http://example.com/accounts/signup/`. I need to show a Terms & Conditions page before going to signup page. Now, any one can type this URL directly in browser to go to signup page without reading the T&C page. But they should.

How could I do this? Is there any way to add a decorator to that view or any other ways without decorator? The same applies to any admin views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use django session to store an information if current user has accepted the terms.

If the user hasn't do that, simply redirect him to T&C page.

If you're having difficulties with wrapping third app view function with such checking code, try to implement that logic using middleware [process_view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs#process-view) method.

The `view_func` argument and `request.session` is what you're looking for.

Comment: This solved my problem. But the only concern is this middleware will be called for all my views. Can it be fixed somehow?

Comment: You can determine if you're wrapping desired view by making use of `view_func` argument.